# Class not abstract, doesn't override abstract method

Tags: java, swing, abstract-class, actionlistener, abstract

I've read most of the other questions on non-Abstract classes with abstract methods and I don't think I understood any of it. So heres my problem:

I'm attempting to make a metronome, for the metronome to 'click' and play sound I copied the code from http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~illah/CLASSDOCS/javasound.pdf .

The code below is a super basic program that creates a JFrame, JPanel, and JButtton. When the Button (ClickForSound) is clicked, it should play the sound.

```
import java.net.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.applet.*;

class PlsWork implements ActionListener{
 JPanel JPanelThing = new JPanel();

 public PlsWork() {
  //make frame to hold everything
  JFrame Frame4HoldinSheit = new JFrame("Sound Player");

  //set up frame
  Frame4HoldinSheit.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
  Frame4HoldinSheit.setSize(300, 300);
  Frame4HoldinSheit.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

  // make button for playing sound
  JButton ClickForSound = new JButton("Click Me");
  ClickForSound.addActionListener(this);

  //add button to panel, then panel to frame
  Frame4HoldinSheit.add(JPanelThing);
  JPanelThing.add(ClickForSound);
 }

 public void actionPreformed(ActionEvent ae) {
  //if button is pressed
  if(ae.getActionCommand().equals("Click Me")){
    try {
        //make a AudioClip 
        AudioClip MetSound = Applet.newAudioClip(
            //Using this file (FOUND HERE)
            new  URL( "C:/Users/jheld7499/desktop/4d.wav" ));
            MetSound.play();
    } catch (java.net.MalformedURLException murle) {
        //ya done goofed on where u thought the file was
        System.out.println("Malformed URL Exception"); }
  }
 }

 public static void main(String args[]){
  SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() { public void run() {
      //run the program
      new PlsWork();} });
 }
}
```

The error I get is that Class PlsWork is not abstract and thus does not override abstract method PlsWork

```
sound.java:8: error: PlsWork is not abstract and does not override 
abstract method actionPerformed(ActionEvent) in ActionListener
class PlsWork implements ActionListener{
^
1 error
```

Also PLEASE talk to me like an idiot as I have almost no understanding of what abstract means or how to make a method abstract, if I want anything to be abstract or anything else.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html

Comment: "The error I get is that Class PlsWork is not abstract and thus does not override abstract method PlsWork" - that is _not_ what the error message says. Read it again.

Answer (score 3):

Check your syntax: `actionPerformed != actionPreformed`. Adding the `@Override` annotation can be helpful in other, non-compile time error situations (eg you are overriding a non-abstract method of a subclass)

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

}
```

Comment: One of those occasions the compiler error message is actually useful!

Comment: @TEK, if you actually take a look, Java is one of the languages that present the most useful compiler errors.